# dpkg unsatisfied dependencies, now apt-get wants to remove whole system

Tags: apt, dpkg

firstly, I'm sorry for my terminal output in portuguese, but I guess it is still understandable.

I am using Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 and I tried to update the `GNOME Online Accounts` packages by downloading the following .deb files from `packages.ubuntu.com` for the Ubuntu 14.10 version:

```
libgoa-backend-1.0-dev_3.12.4-1_amd64.deb
libgoa-backend-1.0-1_3.12.4-1_amd64.deb
libgoa-1.0-dev_3.12.4-1_amd64.deb
libgoa-1.0-0b_3.12.4-1_amd64.deb
gnome-online-accounts_3.12.4-1_amd64.deb
gir1.2-goa-1.0_3.12.4-1_amd64.deb
```

After downloading them in the same folder, I run the command `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`, but it didn't install the packages, instead it showed errors due to packages which them depend doesn't meet the required version (and Ubuntu have no way to install them since they are not in this version's repositories).

So now every time I want to install anything through `apt-get`, Ubuntu tells me to run `apt-get -f install` to fix the errors. This is the list of packages it needs to install/uninstall/update:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
Corrigindo dependências... Pronto
Os seguintes pacotes foram instalados automaticamente e já não são necessários:

# THESE PACKAGES HAVE BEEN PREVIOUSLY INSTALLED AND ARE NO LONGER NECESSARY

  account-plugin-windows-live gir1.2-gweather-3.0 libatk-bridge2.0-dev
  libatk1.0-dev libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev libexpat1-dev
  libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev
  libgtk-3-dev libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0 libice-dev libpango1.0-dev
  libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0 libpixman-1-dev libpng12-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev
  librest-dev libsm-dev libsoup2.4-dev libwayland-dev libx11-dev libx11-doc
  libxau-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb1-dev libxcomposite-dev
  libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev
  libxft-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxml2-dev
  libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev pkg-config signon-plugin-password
  x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-core-dev x11proto-damage-dev
  x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev x11proto-randr-dev
  x11proto-render-dev x11proto-xext-dev x11proto-xinerama-dev
  xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev zlib1g-dev
Utilize 'apt-get autoremove' para os remover.
Os pacotes extra a seguir serão instalados:

# THE FOLLOWING PACKAGES WILL BE INSTALLED

  debhelper dh-apparmor libatk-bridge2.0-dev libatk1.0-dev
  libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev libept1.4.12 libexpat1-dev
  libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev
  libgtk-3-dev libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0 libice-dev
  libmail-sendmail-perl libpango1.0-dev libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0
  libpixman-1-dev libpng12-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev librest-dev libsm-dev
  libsoup2.4-dev libwayland-dev libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev
  libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb1-dev libxcomposite-dev
  libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev
  libxft-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxml2-dev
  libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev pkg-config po-debconf x11proto-composite-dev
  x11proto-core-dev x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-input-dev
  x11proto-kb-dev x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-render-dev x11proto-xext-dev
  x11proto-xinerama-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev zlib1g-dev
Pacotes sugeridos:
  dh-make apparmor-easyprof libcairo2-doc libglib2.0-doc libgtk-3-doc
  libice-doc libpango1.0-doc imagemagick libsm-doc libsoup2.4-doc libxcb-doc
  libxext-doc libmail-box-perl
Os pacotes a seguir serão REMOVIDOS:

# THE FOLLOWING PACKAGES WILL BE REMOVED

  account-plugin-aim account-plugin-jabber account-plugin-salut
  account-plugin-yahoo empathy evolution evolution-data-server
  evolution-data-server-online-accounts evolution-indicator evolution-plugins
  gdm gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-zpj-0.0 gnome-contacts
  gnome-control-center gnome-documents gnome-online-accounts
  gnome-online-miners gnome-shell gnome-shell-extension-weather
  gnome-shell-extensions grilo-plugins-0.2 gvfs-backends-goa libevolution
  libfolks-eds25 libgdata13 libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-dev libgoa-backend-1.0-1
  libgoa-backend-1.0-dev libzapojit-0.0-0 mcp-account-manager-uoa
  nautilus-sendto-empathy ubuntu-gnome-desktop
Os NOVOS pacotes a seguir serão instalados:

# THE NEW FOLLOWING PACKAGES WILL BE INSTALLED

  debhelper dh-apparmor libatk-bridge2.0-dev libatk1.0-dev
  libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev libept1.4.12 libexpat1-dev
  libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev
  libgtk-3-dev libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0 libice-dev
  libmail-sendmail-perl libpango1.0-dev libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0
  libpixman-1-dev libpng12-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev librest-dev libsm-dev
  libsoup2.4-dev libwayland-dev libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev
  libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb1-dev libxcomposite-dev
  libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev
  libxft-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxml2-dev
  libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev pkg-config po-debconf x11proto-composite-dev
  x11proto-core-dev x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-input-dev
  x11proto-kb-dev x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-render-dev x11proto-xext-dev
  x11proto-xinerama-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev zlib1g-dev
0 pacotes atualizados, 61 pacotes novos instalados, 35 a serem removidos e 22 não atualizados.
7 pacotes não totalmente instalados ou removidos.
É preciso baixar 12,0 MB de arquivos.
Depois desta operação, 25,0 MB adicionais de espaço em disco serão usados.
Você quer continuar? [S/n]
```

Along packages needed to be removed are even `gdm`. This is 100% sure to make the system useless. What can I do to fix this issue? I don't care if I can't install the new version of `goa` anymore.

Comment: Try downloading the corresponding packages for 14.04 and installing them.

Comment: @muru Thanks, your suggestion fixed my issue. After downloading the corresponding packages for Ubuntu 14.04 and installing them with `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`, it was asked again to run `sudo apt-get -f install`, but this time it asked just to install a few packages and none to be removed. After doing this everything works fine again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-get` always favours the highest version installed - so instead of removing/downgrading the GOA packages, it will try to remove the packages which depend on the lower version. One solution is to get the older packages and install them using `dpkg -i` - you can download from [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com) or use `apt-get download`, which should download the highest version in the repositories. If you do wish to try out newer versions, use the GNOME3 PPAs:

1. The main PPA: [`ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3)
2. The staging PPA: [`ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging`](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging)
3. The testing PPA: [`ppa:ricotz/testing`](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/ubuntu/testing)

Comment: Thanks, +1 for adding the PPAs, I should have tried that before installing packages by hand. I forgot about them.